# Get soap server "referer" (in php)

Tags: php, soap

How can i get from what website the soap server was called? Already tried the $_SERVER variable but no information about the source is saved there.

My soap server is accessed from various websites (ex site1.com, site2.com etc). How can i get inside the soap server class if it was from site1.com or site2.com

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

You could get the IP address of the machine that the request came from, but multiple domains could resolve to it.

If you care about "who" is making the request, then you need to hand out identifying credentials and require they be included in the request.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and additional solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You might try overriding [SoapServer::handle()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapserver.handle.php) and looking at the raw Soap request.  Though as @Quentin says, YMMV.